# Apacher Hadoop , Apacher Hive on Apache Spark JAVA_9 common-lang version

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

Trying set Hive use Spark as engine.

After long configurations got, Timeout error.

Application log file yarn logs -applicationId <app_id>

```
ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: JAVA_9
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: JAVA_9
        at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<init>(StorageUtils.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<clinit>(StorageUtils.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:370)
```

The Error is in file
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/StorageUtils.scala

```
private val bufferCleaner: DirectBuffer => Unit =
if (SystemUtils.isJavaVersionAtLeast(JavaVersion.JAVA_9)) {
  val cleanerMethod =
    Utils.classForName("sun.misc.Unsafe").getMethod("invokeCleaner", classOf[ByteBuffer])
  val unsafeField = classOf[Unsafe].getDeclaredField("theUnsafe")
  unsafeField.setAccessible(true)
  ..
```

After research  found out that problem is in common-lang3* jar file.
I updated all on files on server using with older versions to commons-lang3-3.9.jar jars in hadoop share , hive ,etc .

https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/JavaVersion.java

But still getting this error .

Comment: maybe it has to do with the java version installed on your server, or the one your hive is configured to use.

this might help: https://hadooptutorials.info/2020/10/11/part-5-using-spark-as-execution-engine-for-hive-2/

Comment: I am also facing the same. The jar commons-lang3-3.9.jar do have the JAVA_9 field.

Answer (score 0):

This error(java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: JAVA_9) is there because, there is no enum for java version 9 in in common-lang package you are using in gradle/maven file. Use this version with java 17 -> **org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0**. In StorageUtil$.class, we have this sninnpet.

```
 if (SystemUtils.isJavaVersionAtLeast(JavaVersion.JAVA_9))
```

and this is not present in common-lang package, to verify click on JavaVersion, it will direct you to that class, and check if enum for java version is there or not.
For above version, we have these JAVA VERSION.

```
public enum JavaVersion {

/**
 * The Java version reported by Android. This is not an official Java version number.
 */
JAVA_0_9(1.5f, "0.9"),

/**
 * Java 1.1.
 */
JAVA_1_1(1.1f, "1.1"),

/**
 * Java 1.2.
 */
JAVA_1_2(1.2f, "1.2"),

/**
 * Java 1.3.
 */
JAVA_1_3(1.3f, "1.3"),

/**
 * Java 1.4.
 */
JAVA_1_4(1.4f, "1.4"),

/**
 * Java 1.5.
 */
JAVA_1_5(1.5f, "1.5"),

/**
 * Java 1.6.
 */
JAVA_1_6(1.6f, "1.6"),

/**
 * Java 1.7.
 */
JAVA_1_7(1.7f, "1.7"),

/**
 * Java 1.8.
 */
JAVA_1_8(1.8f, "1.8"),

/**
 * Java 1.9.
 *
 * @deprecated As of release 3.5, replaced by {@link #JAVA_9}
 */
@Deprecated
JAVA_1_9(9.0f, "9"),

/**
 * Java 9.
 *
 * @since 3.5
 */
JAVA_9(9.0f, "9"),

/**
 * Java 10.
 *
 * @since 3.7
 */
JAVA_10(10.0f, "10"),

/**
 * Java 11.
 *
 * @since 3.8
 */
JAVA_11(11.0f, "11"),

/**
 * Java 12.
 *
 * @since 3.9
 */
JAVA_12(12.0f, "12"),

/**
 * Java 13.
 *
 * @since 3.9
 */
JAVA_13(13.0f, "13"),

/**
 * Java 14.
 *
 * @since 3.11
 */
JAVA_14(14.0f, "14"),

/**
 * Java 15.
 *
 * @since 3.11
 */
JAVA_15(15.0f, "15"),

/**
 * Java 16.
 *
 * @since 3.11
 */
JAVA_16(16.0f, "16"),

/**[enter image description here][1]
 * Java 17.
 *
 * @since 3.12.0
 */
JAVA_17(17.0f, "17"),
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case the user was on Spark 3.2.2 with Hadoop which depends on commons-lang3 3.12. commons-lang3 contains the enum `JavaVersion` which contains `JAVA_9`.

In addition the user was adding hive-jdbc-2.1.1-cdh6.3.4-standalone.jar to the classpath which contains a much older version of commons-lang3 which does not contain `JAVA_9`.

The user's Spark installation had `userClassPathFirst` set to `true` and therefore the older version of commons-lang3 was picked up.